# Basement plumbing venting

Tags: plumbing, basement, venting

I am in the process of finishing my basement.  There is currently a bathroom roughed in. My question is on venting.  There is no dedicated vent stack I can access in the basement.  Where is the best place to tie in to the existing plumbing for venting?  [image]

Comment: Can you detail the drawing a little better? I think it's a plan view, and I think the blue dots represent fixtures, but it's not helping you if I'm guessing

Comment: Sorry about that.  The blue dots represent the rough in plumbing.  From left to right.  1st blue dot is tub/shower, 2nd blue dot is toilet and 3rd is for the sink.  My thought was to run a vent from the sink to somewhere in the existing plumbing.

Comment: And are there no vent stacks anywhere in this drawing, even above the clean out/soil stack?

Comment: The only vent pipes I can see on the roof is above the upstairs master  bathroom sink and another bathroom sink.  Looks like it is a 2" vent.  There is a 3" Radon stack out the top from under the slab.  The only plumbing I can see from the basement is coming from fixtures upstairs.  No venting stacks I can see.

Comment: Knowing where the roof penetration is might not help you. You need to determine where existing vents are so you can tie into them. You might have to create new vents ascending which tie into your main waste vent. That's a much broader question than the one you're asking.

Comment: What is a better way to find them than through the roof penetration?  There is no evidence in the basement.

Comment: You need to look behind walls. There might be one above the main waste stack. Without being on-site, I can't even imagine where they might be, but all fixtures need vents, so start by looking near existing fixtures